# Diagnostic Logging not working

Tags: uls

Log files are created but blank.

Confirmed that the "SharePoint 2010 Tracing" is running as local service

Confirmed Farm account is in the "Performance Log Users"

When going to CA > Monitoring > Diagnostic Logging, select "All Categories" .

Least critical event to event log: warning ;

least critical event to trace log: Medium

After I save & return to the page everything is blank again

Comment: Have you checked hard drive storage where log files are saved? Maybe it is running low.

Comment: I cleared 2.5GB on the drive still seeing same results

Comment: can you check and confirm with ULS logs (You can use ulsviwer)

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your case you have the permission issue on the folder where you cofigure the logs.This problem occurs when you change the default path of the Diagnostic logging. Please make sure the following groups having the proper permission on log path.

- WSS_WSP(server\WSS_WSP)
- WSS_ADMIN_WPG(server\WSS_ADMIN_WPG)
- WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG_V4(server\WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG_V4)
- Local Service

Also check the Event Log(application) you will see more helpful info.

[SharePoint 2010 ULS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/leesab/archive/2014/10/14/uls-diagnostic-logs-not-working-0kb-is-size.aspx)